# Push a ViewController and It Pops Right Back

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

I have a view controller with a table view and a UISearchBar. When the view controller is first brought up, the table is populated.  A click on a table row pushes another view controller, it animates up and then pops right back down and returns me to the table.  It does this whether the search bar has been used or not.  I do this push pop kind of action in several view controllers with not problem.  My guess is that the UISearchBar is somehow getting in the way.  Any one have any idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your viewDidDisappear code, or anywhere else you might have a popViewController.  Betting one is getting called somewhere.